# Conditional dependencies in CHEF

Tags: chef, conditional

I have a complicated software stack that I manage with 2 recipes.

```
recipe[stack::foo]
recipe[stack::bar]
```

`foo` is installed on every server, whereas `bar` is installed on only a subset of servers. `bar` depends on the file and service `foo`.

recipe[stack::foo]

```
  file 'fooFile' do
    source 'somewhere'
    notifies :restart, service[barService] #bar needs to be restart first, if it is present
    notifies :restart, service[fooService]
  end

  service 'fooService' do
    action :start
  end
```

recipe[stack::bar]

```
  file 'barFile' do
    source 'somewhere'
  end

  service 'barService' do
    action :start
  end
```

Is it possible to make a conditional dependency, so that if the `bar` recipe is present on the node, it will restart it. If it isn't, it will skip it.

I'm trying something like this

```
  file 'fooFile' do
    source 'somewhere'
    notifies :restart, service[barService] if exists? "service[barService]" 
    notifies :restart, service[fooService]
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered in IRC, and user spuder informed that double-asking is not encouraged.

tl;dr use `resources()` or check the run list.